# How do Projects interact in a Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interop, project, solution

I did some googling but to no awail. Which is probably due to  not knowing the correct lingo.

How do Projects interact/ how would you actualy write the interface between them.

Im not looking for the theory, which was quit easy to find on the msdn, but for the practical application in the VS-enviroment, how to write a library (dll)/ how to have projects interact with each other, and so on.

I do not ask you to do my work. But some online resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is accessing classes and such from other projects in your solution, all you have to do is add the project as a reference and include its namespace in the file you want to use things from the other project in.

To add a reference, right click References in the solution explorer, then Add Reference->Solution->Projects->Project you want to add.

Comment: as i understand it, one should have a project for each part of the program, one for the UI, one for logic and so on; is that just a glorifyied namespace?

Comment: You should only make new projects for big things that you will reuse in other programs later. If you just want to organize, you can make separate code files.